Locust POST request does not return expected validation message from form submission
I am trying to simulate a form submission using Locust in Python. When manually submitting the form in a browser with incomplete data, I see the expected validation message: "Please make sure all fields are correctly filled in!". However, when I simulate the same form submission using Locust, the message does not appear in the response.text.
URL - https://www.globalsqa.com/
Steps

Manual Testing:

I opened the form page in a browser.

Navigate to the Contacts Us page

I filled in the form with incomplete data.

Upon submitting, the validation message "Please make sure all fields are correctly filled in!" appeared, indicating that the server correctly detects the incomplete data.



Locust Simulation:

I wrote a Locust script to simulate the form submission with the same incomplete data.

The form is submitted via a POST request, but the expected validation message is not present in the response.text.

Instead, the submission seems to be processed as if no validation error occurred.




Here’s the Locust test script I'm using:
from locust import HttpUser, task, between

class DemoTest(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)  # Users will wait between 1 and 5 seconds between tasks

    @task
    def load_homepage(self):
        print("Loading Home page")
        res = self.client.get("/")
        print("res status_code home page:", res.status_code)

    @task
    def load_contact_us(self):
        print("Loading Contact Us page")
        headers = {'Accept': 'text/html'}
        res = self.client.get("/member/login", headers=headers)
        print("res status_code contact us page:", res.status_code)
        print("res url:", res.url)
        print("res headers:", res.headers)

    @task
    def submit_contact_form(self):
        form_url = "/contact-us/"
        form_data = {
            "comment_name": "John Doe",
            "email": "johndoe@example.com",
            "subject": "Test Subject",
            "comment": "This is a test message from Locust."
        }
        print("Submitting contact form")
        response = self.client.post(form_url, data=form_data)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Form submission successful (200 OK)")

        # Check for expected validation message
        if "Please make sure all fields are correctly filled in!" in response.text:
            print("Validation message displayed: 'Please make sure all fields are correctly filled in!'")
        else:
            print("Form submission was processed, no validation errors detected.")

Even though I expect the validation message "Please make sure all fields are correctly filled in!" to appear after the form submission, it doesn't show up in response.text.
Questions:
Am I missing something in my form data or request setup that could prevent the validation message from appearing?
Is there a better way to debug or inspect the actual server response to understand why this message is missing?
Could this issue be related to server-side form validation logic, and if so, how can I simulate this more accurately?
Any help would be appreciated!
